# The gridfs "list" method returns empty list with non empty collection

Tags: python, mongodb, list, pymongo, gridfs

Can we get the count of files stored in `GridFS` using PyMongo other than using list function?

Also, when I try the `list()` method under `gridfs`, it gives me an empty list although when there are files in the DB. Am able to retrieve the files using `get()` method by using the `_id`.
Does the list() function return list of all the files stored under `gridfs` `db` if we save the files without filenames and depend on the `_id` value instead.

Code:

```
client = pymongo.MongoClient(connect=False)
grid_db = client['gridDB']
fs = gridfs.GridFS(grid_db)
# Save an image
img_identifier = fs.put(img, encoding="utf-8")
# List the files stored
print fs.list()
'''[] Console shows empty array'''
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the expected result. The reason is that you didn't set a value for the field [`filename`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/gridfs/grid_file.html#gridfs.grid_file.GridIn.filename) during insert (put), however the `list` method returns [`distinct`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.distinct) values for the `filename` field in the collection. So it returns empty list if the field doesn't exist in the collection. [See the `list()` method implementation](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/0b34f9702ca8bed45792a53287d33a2292b99152/gridfs/__init__.py#L226-237).

```
def list(self):
    """List the names of all files stored in this instance of
    :class:`GridFS`.
    .. versionchanged:: 3.1
       ``list`` no longer ensures indexes.
    """
    # With an index, distinct includes documents with no filename
    # as None.
    return [
        name for name in self.__files.distinct("filename")
        if name is not None]
```

Demo:

```
>>> import pprint  
>>> from pymongo import MongoClient
>>> import gridfs
>>> client = MongoClient()
>>> db = client.demo
>>> fs = gridfs.GridFS(db)
>>> fs.put('img.jpg', encoding='utf-8')
ObjectId('573af0960acf4555437ceaa9')
>>> fs.list()
[]
>>> pprint.pprint(db['fs.files'].find_one())
{'_id': ObjectId('573af0960acf4555437ceaa9'),
 'chunkSize': 261120,
 'encoding': 'utf-8',
 'length': 7,
 'md5': '82341a6c6f03e3af261a95ba81050c0a',
 'uploadDate': datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 17, 10, 21, 11, 38000)}
```

As you can see, the  field `filename` doesn't exist in your document. Now let's pass in the `filename` argument:

```
>>> client.drop_database(db) # drop our demo database
>>> fs.put('img.jpg', encoding='utf-8', filename='img.jpg')
ObjectId('573af1740acf4555437ceaab')
>>> fs.list()
['img.jpg']
>>> pprint.pprint(db['fs.files'].find_one())
{'_id': ObjectId('573af1740acf4555437ceaab'),
 'chunkSize': 261120,
 'encoding': 'utf-8',
 'filename': 'img.jpg',
 'length': 7,
 'md5': '82341a6c6f03e3af261a95ba81050c0a',
 'uploadDate': datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 17, 10, 24, 53, 449000)}
```

As you can see, `list` returns a list of 'filename' values.